# How to implement a simple DataSet authoring workflow in CKAN?

Tags: ckan

Is it possible to implement though CKAN plugins/extensions a workflow that allows Organization admins or Sysadmins preview a DataSet, optionally adding some feedback and sending it back to the editor for corrections before making it public?

We still don't have a clear idea of what kind of workflow we want to implement, but I think that with a combination of using [Organizations](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/authorization.html) with private DataSets reviewed by Organization admins and then made public might work.

What we don't have sorted out yet is how to track which DataSets have been reviewed, which ones were returned for corrections, etc...

Can this be done with [Custom Fields](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html)?

BTW, we're using CKAN 2.3 with datastore and datapusher enabled.

Comment: You could implement this yourself, but this would be quite some effort, depending on your needs. The general feature is on the roadmap (see https://github.com/ckan/ideas-and-roadmap/issues/108), and might get implemented in a future version of CKAN.